Shower mixing valve leaking
I have a Hansgrohe Ecostat Pressure Balance Trim S valve that's leaking. The dripping is coming from the shower head -- about 1 drip a second. This problem started when we replaced our hot water heater, during which we played with the screws behind the trim. We've since tried to play with the screws again, but to no avail. It's possible the leaking was happening before the hot water heater was installed and therefore a red herring. It's also possible that the new water heater has a bit higher pressure and caused the leak to happen. Or maybe we just unseated a seal of some sort.
I'm not sure what to do next. As an extra obstacle, there's no shutoff to this unit or fixture -- I'd have to shut down the whole building (it's an old building with poor plumbing design). So I'm ideally looking for a fix that can be done with the water on.
https://www.hansgrohe-usa.com/articledetail-ecostat-pressure-balance-trim-s-04233000 has more details on the fixture.

do you have access to pipes before the fixture?

Yes -- in the basement at the hot water heater (tank) and cold supply (but again, no shutoff on the cold). And whatever I can access behind the mixer's trim.

a plumber can freeze the water pipe to shut off water and install a main shutoff valve

Ok great. And when we get the shutoff in place, what can be done other than replace the mixer?

According to the instructions in your link, the mixer has stop valves, so you can turn the water off and service or replace the mixer valve. You can use those instructions in reverse to remove the trim, access and turn off the stop valves, remove and inspect the cartridge.
Possibly in swapping the heater you released debris that is clogging the cartridge. Possibly you'll see the debris,and can clear it. Possibly by opening the cartridge it will clear itself, you won't see anything but it will then stop leaking.   If the cartridge has failed you hopefully will be able to replace it under the manufacturer's lifetime warranty.
Those are the optimistic possibilities. :)
If you do open it, good idea to run the flush operation from the instructions.

The debris idea should be the only thing that would match with the swapping of the heater.

Good answer - clean the cartridge.   90% of the time this works as is.   10% you need to order gaskets.    5% you mess up and break something.

@DMoore 5% becomes worse if you raise the bar to successfully reusing all tiny decorative set screw caps.  ;)
